# Bootstrap 5 grid, how to customize the grid gutters at different breakpoints (not using utility classes)?

Tags: sass, bootstrap-5, gutter

How can I customize Bootstrap 5 to have different grid gutters at different breakpoints?  I don't want to use the grid spacing utility classes because those would be hard coded all over the place in markup and a pain to change.

It looks like Bootstrap 5 has this variable as the default gutter width across the board:

```
$grid-gutter-width: 1.5rem;
```

What I want is something like this (the values are just made up to illustrate the idea):

```
$grid-gutter-width-sm: 1rem;
$grid-gutter-width-md: 1.5rem;
$grid-gutter-width-lg: 2rem;
$grid-gutter-width-xl: 2.5rem;
```

Comment: According to the official documentation the gutter classes do have responsive breakpoints, so you should be able to just use, let's say `g-0  g-lg-2` for no gutters till medium and then g-2 (0.75rem) from large.

Comment: I think those gutter classes are part of "grid spacing utility classes", and they want to globally change the gutter width on each breakpoint.

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky because the gutter is used to build all the `container*`, `row` and `col*`. You can make a custom map with the gutter widths for each breakpoint, and then iterate the map to re-build the grid at each breakpoint:

```
@import "functions";
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";

$custom-gutter-widths: (
  sm: 1rem,
  md: 1.5rem,
  lg: 2rem,
  xl: 2.5rem,
  xxl: 3rem,
);

@import "bootstrap";

@each $breakpoint, $gutterwidth in $custom-gutter-widths {
    $container-padding-x: $gutterwidth*.5;
    $grid-gutter-width: $gutterwidth;
    @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint, $grid-breakpoints) {
        .container,
        .container-fluid {
            @include make-container();
        }
        
        .row {
            @include make-row();
            
            > * {
              @include make-col-ready();
            }
        }
        @include make-grid-columns();
        
    }
}
```

[Bootstrap SASS on Codeply](https://codeply.com/p/2zyf8IovFI)

Note: This is making a lot of extra CSS!

Answer (score 2):

I think adding breakpoint in body to overwrite `--bs-gutter-x` should be enough:

```
body {
  @include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
    --bs-gutter-x: 1rem;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-down(md) {
    --bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-down(lg) {
    --bs-gutter-x: 2rem;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-down(xl) {
    --bs-gutter-x: 2.5rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked in a .row with Bootstrap 5.2